# React-Native filter array

Tags: arrays, react-native

I have this const:

```
const States = [
  {
    label: "Alaska",
    value: "AK"
  },
  {
    label: "District of Columbia",
    value: "DC"
  },
  {
    label: "Florida",
    value: "FL"
  },
  {
    label: "Mississippi",
    value: "MS"
  },
  {
    label: "Wyoming",
    value: "WY"
  }
];
```

I would like to return the label of a given value. I tried with map() but got nowhere. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is unclear, like exactly what you need. Is it that you only need to display the label for only a given particular value or just display the labels for each value? For the first option, what you can do is use the filter function, like

```
States.filter(state => { if(state.value == 'AK'){ return <Text>{state.label}</Text>}})
```

in this case, above, you want to just print the label of the only state with a value of 'AK'.

And for the second case where you want to print all the labels for each state, then you can proceed with your map() func.

```
States.map(state => { return(<Text>{state.label}</Text>)})
```

Hope this will suffice both the possibilities of your question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your usage is wrong. Use the `map` to return.

**Usage**

```js
const list = States.map(
  (info, index) => (
  <View key={index}>
    <Text>{info.label}</Text>
    <Text>{info.value}</Text>
  </View>
)
);
```